# How can I have separate arrays in this shared prototype?

Tags: javascript, prototype

Given this:

```
var p = function(){}; 
p.prototype = { id : null, arr : []}
var a = new p(); 
var b = new p();
a.id = 1;
a.arr.push(5);
alert(b.arr[0]);
```

The alert reads `5` meaning that a.arr == b.arr, however a.id and b.id are separate (a.id != b.id). How can I make it so that a.arr != b.arr?

Constraints:

p must be able to have `new p()` used. Or, there must be a way to make unique p's.

Comment: What might be helpful is to add the array as a prototype after you create it. So then the id isn't persistent across object creation, but the array contents are, if I am understanding what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want id and arr to be unique to each instance of p you need to instantiate them inside the p constructor.  The prototype object should only be used for shared constants and functions.

```
var p = function(){
    this.id = null;
    this.arr = [];
}; 

var a = new p(); 
var b = new p();

a.id = 1;
a.arr.push(5);
alert(b.arr[0]);
```